# Replacing a background-image bij jQuery not working on moblie devices

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to replace an inline background-image with jQuery when the website is loaded on a mobile device, and/or when the screen is smaller than 767px.

The site is where I am trying to do this is: http://vormgegeven.com/

And the image I try to replace is the first image on the homepage(slider) (the blue sky with 'vormgegeven.').

This all works fine on my desktop, but not on any of my mobile devices.
I tried to alert the old background-image src first, to check if I could reach it, but the alert replies with 'none' on mobile (on desktop works fine).

It seems like a css targeting problem, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
function replacePrimarySliderImage() {
    $oldImg = $("#mainImageHolder .primaryHolder .parallax-slider-img").css('background-image');
    alert($oldImg);
    $newImg = $oldImg.replace("vormgegeven.jpg","vormgegeven_mobile.jpg");
    $( "#mainImageHolder .primaryHolder .parallax-slider-img" ).css("background-image", $newImg);
}
```

Comment: Your .primaryHolder only exists for some time in your DOM. my guess is you are either trying to update the image at point of time where it is not in DOM. Keep in mind mobile connection and CPU power are less powerfull then desktop, hence you might be trying to update it either before it gets in DOM or after it changes. .primaryHolder gets completely removed from  DOM once your parallax goes to 2nd image.

Comment: So I have to catch the moment that the .primaryHolder is loaded, and then apply my replacement script ?

Comment: I don't know how it is exactly being build and how it is connected and when the function is being called. But from my inspection on your site that block gets completely removed from DOM. You said on your desktop it changes the images? You still have 4 of them going, does the picture stay changed next time it gets to it?

Comment: It is a wordpress ChreeyFramework slider. And yes, the image gets replaced by the original every time it cycles.

Comment: Well, never worked with wordpress, but would put my finger there as a problem (things getting removed from DOM and then added again + I don't see how and when do you call your function, but your function should work in normal circumstances so issue has to be with Chreey thing and I can see your code works in fiddle as well)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function replacePrimarySliderImage() {

    $newImg = "vormgegeven_mobile.jpg";
    $( "#mainImageHolder .primaryHolder .parallax-slider-img" ).css("background-image", $newImg);
}
```

Comment: Still not working on mobile. It seems like jQuery is unable to find the inline css.

Comment: Fiddle is working for me... https://jsfiddle.net/g25g0q2b/2/ It replaces the image after 5 seconds. If i inspect the image the url is http://www.vormgegeven.com/wp-content/uploads/vormgegeven_mobile.jpg. It also works on my Galaxy s4